# Proving $x<y<z \implies \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} \le \frac{f(z)-f(y)}{z-y}$

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is convex on $I$ and $(x,y,z)\in I^3$:

How to prove that:

$$x<y<z \implies \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} \le \frac{f(z)-f(y)}{z-y}$$

Comment: When $y=x+\varepsilon$, and $z=y+\varepsilon$, you get the derivative, which is non-decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

First the inequality you need to prove is equal to: $(z-x) f(y) \le (y-x) f(z)+(z-y) f(x)$. Write $y=tx+(1-t)z$. You should get the desired result.